# How to re-number ttyUSB from 0?

Tags: usb

Sometime when I disconnect and reconnect my USB-to-serial converter, the /dev/ttyUSB numbers start from ttyUSB1 instead of ttyUSB0.

```
$ sudo dmesg |grep ttyUSB0
[    6.050433] usb 1-4: cp210x converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 6970.689605] cp210x ttyUSB0: failed set request 0x12 status: -19
[ 6970.689624] cp210x ttyUSB0: failed set request 0x0 status: -19
[ 6970.689879] cp210x ttyUSB0: cp210x converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
```

How can I release ttyUSB0 without restarting the computer, so that the ports for the converter always start from ttyUSB0?

Comment: Rather than trying to "fix" the device node numbering, I'd suggest adding a UDEV rule that creates a custom symlink based on the device's attributes. See for example [How to match a ttyUSBX device to a usb serial device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81754/how-to-match-a-ttyusbx-device-to-a-usb-serial-device)

Comment: That's a better way to go. My converter creates two serial ports:

[[$ ls -l /sys/bus/usb-serial/devices/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 1月   5 14:11 ttyUSB0 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8.2/1-8.2.2/1-8.2.2:1.0/ttyUSB0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 1月   5 14:11 ttyUSB1 -> ../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8.2/1-8.2.2/1-8.2.2:1.1/ttyUSB1]]

How do I differentiate them as they have the same vendor ID and product ID?

Answer (score 0):

This is a terrible hack and I suggest looking into better more sustainable long term solutions for whatever you are coding but as a direct answer to your question, unbinding and rebinding the usb device will cause a re-enumeration of ttyUSB#.
Make sure to run this in a script or you may lose access to your keyboard.

```
echo "usb1" | tee -a unbind
echo "usb1" | tee -a bind
lsusb > /dev/null
```